# How can I track Android install referrers with Amazon Appstore?

Tags: android, google-play, referrer, amazon-appstore

I am currently tracking referrers with Android Market and Google Analytics as described here:
http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/android/#android-market-tracking

Is there a similar solution that can be used for Amazon Appstore?

Comment: Is link bad? Are you actually referring to this: http://www.localytics.com/docs/android-market-campaign-analytics/ or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: were you able to find the answer ? The receiver tag is mentioned as supported for the manifest in amazon app store but dont know if the install referrer will be handled by amazon app store.

Answer (score 1):

Does the Amazon Appstore prevent you from using Google Analytics? Well... not that I would be surprised, given how eager they are to pretend that Google Play does not exist.

In any case, [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/index.html) is another popular analytics alternative for Android. I use it for Apps on the Amazon Appstore, so I know they don't have an issue with that. It also works well enough that I've never seen the point of moving over to the Google Analytics suite.

Edit: Your question is not 100% clear (since the link just points to Google Analytics), but is the problem that you want to be able to track referrers in the Amazon appstore app/website?

That is obviously a different cup of tea. But in that case, my advice is really simple: send a mail to the Amazon appstore crew, explain what you want, and ask them if they can provide this service. The Amazon appstore has some weaknesses, but the one big advantage that they have is that they have actual people willing to talk and listen to their developers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the URL structure defined at the following link:
https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/in-app-purchasing/sample-code/deeplink.html
Use the `ref=` tag as described at the bottom of the linked webpage

Comment: I can't find that `ref` parameter. Is it an undocumented parameter?

Comment: I ask to amazon to that parameter and they don't use on Android apps

Comment: The linked web page has changed so it seems this is no longer supported (or not documented...)